# GO - ¿Puntero o Variable para referenciar WaitGroups?

Tags: variables, punteros, go

Según las siguientes declaraciones de funciones del paquete sync:

Add -------> func (wg *WaitGroup) Add(delta int)

Done ------> func (wg *WaitGroup) Done()

Wait ------> func (wg *WaitGroup) Wait()

Entiendo que las 3 funciones son llamadas por un puntero a WaitGroup, ¿verdad?

Si esto es correcto, en el siguiente código, entiendo por qué se llama a la función Done usando un puntero, pero no entiendo por qué a las funciones Add y Wait se las llama usando una variable (no un puntero):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

func worker(id int, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {

    defer wg.Done()

    fmt.Printf("Worker %d starting\n", id)

    time.Sleep(time.Second)
    fmt.Printf("Worker %d done\n", id)
}

func main() {

    var wg sync.WaitGroup

    for i := 1; i <= 5; i++ {
        wg.Add(1)
        go worker(i, &wg)
    }

    wg.Wait()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Go hace una conversión automática entre valores y punteros cuando se llama a una función definida sobre un tipo concreto. De hecho, puedes probar tu función con punteros y el resultado será el mismo:

```
func main() {

var wg sync.WaitGroup

for i := 1; i <= 5; i++ {
    (&wg).Add(1)
    go worker(i, &wg)
}
(&wg).Wait()
```

El motivo principal de utilizar punteros en la función worker es afectar a la variable recibida por argumentos y no simplemente utilizar su valor. Si eliminas los punteros redefiniendo la función, el programa se ejecutará perfectamente (gracias a la conversión automática) aunque generarás un `deadlock`